# Dockerized NextJs + NodeJs app with Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, https, next.js13

I'm quite lost into a big issue from my project.

To be simple : i've got a docker compose with a few stack : a DB, a backend (express, nodejs), a frontend (nextjs), and a reverse proxy.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  backend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: base
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/home/node/app/src
      - ./backend/nodemon.json:/home/node/app/nodemon.json
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: backend
    expose:
      - '8000'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: npm run production
    environment:
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8000/health || exit 1"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - docker-network

  db:
    restart: always
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '5433:${DB_PORT}'
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    networks:
      - docker-network

  frontend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: base
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/home/node/front-app
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    command: yarn start
    networks:
      - docker-network

  nginx:
    container_name: 'nginx'
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX.fr/fullchain.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX.fr/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX.frprivkey.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX.fr/privkey.pem
    networks:
      - docker-network
    restart: always
  

volumes: 
 data: {}

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my nginx conf :

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    # for certbot renewal
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /data/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        # Port that next js is running on
        proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }



    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The issue is, i am not able to configure the frontend to communicate with the backend : I've got to pass by the domain, so in https to avoid cors issue as the website is served in https, but i don't know, not successful, on how to configure nginx to handle the frontend to backend request. Fyi, those requests are simple fetch in NextJS but I'm a bit lost on what ip/adress or anything to target and how to configure nginx ...

Could someone help me clarify this ?

I tried to configure Nginx with another server but it did'nt worked :

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;

        # Standard proxy settings
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd add another path to the Nginx configuration to proxy to the backend service, on the same port.  Then when your (browser-based) frontend calls the backend, it can use a path-only URL without a port.  [This answer](/a/77060234) has an example.